# AVCaptureInput breaks at line 129 after session starts running

Tags: xcode, swift

I received a weird error saying

```
[AVCaptureInput attachToFigCaptureSession:]_block_invoke, file
/SourceCache/EmbeddedAVFoundation/EmbeddedAVFoundation-
887.52/Aspen/AVCaptureInput.m, line 129.
```

What is this error? How it happened?

It happened when I call `session.startRunning()` where `session` is a `AVCaptureSession!`

Comment: That's the location, is there an actual error message?

Comment: That is the problem. This is all it says. What is before is simply the date and the file which this error is occurred in.